# deleting values from foreign key tables in SSMS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ssms-2012

Let's say I have tbl1, tbl2, and tbl3, this is what they look like

```
 tbl1
 UnitID         PK
 SomeField      varchar
 SomeField2     varchar


 tbl2 
 UnitID         PK
 ServiceID      PK
 SomeField3     varchar


 tbl3
 UnitID         PK
 ChangeID       PK
 SomeField4     varchar
```

SO I have three tables in my simple app. Due to some constraints, the data needs to be split up in multiple tables

The user will go to enter a UnitID values in tbl1, then they will add additional data and that data will be stored in tbl2 and tbl3 with the same UnitID and their own corresponding PK's (ServiceID, ChangeID).

WHat I'm looking to see if it can be done is if i delete a value from tbl1, say UnitID=2, am I able to automatically delete all corresponding values from tbl2 and tbl3 with that same UnitID? Or do I have to basically have a delete statement for each table?

I found a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/delete-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017) that is referring to delete foreign key relationships but it shows that it is starting SQL 2016, I'm working in SSMS 2012.

Is something like this possible? The reason why I'm asking is because this is a very simplified view of my tables, I will actually have about 20 tables, and there might be a time where I need to delete that UnitID from every single table in my app. I'm trying to make the code as efficient as possible.

The app is coded with Asp.Net, and VB.NET

I understand that I can simply do

```
Delete * from tbl1 where UnitID=2
Delete * from tbl2 where UnitID=2
```

but this seems tedious. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Drop your existing foreign key constraint if you have already created your table relationships and you can add new foreign key constraint with cascade delete.

```
ALTER TABLE child_table
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_name
    FOREIGN KEY (child_col1, child_col2, ... child_col_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (parent_col1, parent_col2, ... parent_col_n)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

If you are going to create new tables then you can have foreign key constraint with Cascade delete.

```
CREATE TABLE child_table
( parent_col1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_col1 INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT fk_name
    FOREIGN KEY (child_col1, child_col2, ... child_col_n)
    REFERENCES products (parent_col1, parent_col2, ... parent_col_n)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```